# I am Trying to execute a simple EJS program, But getting Unexpected Token ')' error while compiling EJS

Tags: javascript, html, express, typeerror, ejs

I am going to show my code here: It is a very simple one to just display Either Weekday or Weekend.
Installed EJS package from NPM installer

This is list.ejs (inside the views folder)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>T Do List</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The EJS is represented by <%= EJS =%> -->
   <h1>It is a <%= kindOfDay =%> !</h1> <!-- Corrected -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is the app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.set('view engine','ejs'); //for EJS
    
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
    
        var today = new Date();
        var currentDay = today.getDay();
        var day = "";
    
        if(currentDay === 6 || currentDay === 0) // Sunday - Saturday : 0:6
        {
            day = "weekend";
             // list has to exist in views folder || EJS keyword has to match the {key: value} pair
    
        }
        else {
            day = "weekday";
            
        }
    
        res.render("list", {kindOfDay: day}); 
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Server running at port 3000");
    })
```

This is the index.html file

And this is the error I am getting :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in ..\todoList-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (..\todoList-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:662:12)
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated: Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to load an node express script into a browser webpage? That won't work. They're two completely different JS environments.

Comment: this is how it has to be ig ` <%= EJS =%>` and you're doing `<%- kindOfDay %>`

Comment: Yes corrected the correct EJS format. However, trying to just use express and list.ejs to run this. won't work is it?. Any thought on alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the [tag](https://github.com/mde/ejs#tags) is - `<%=` and should be ends with `%>`. You have added `=` on both sides. Please remove from the ending tag. It should be like -

```html
<h1>It is a <%= kindOfDay %> !</h1>
```

Also, the way you added comment is not correct in Ejs.

```html
<!-- The EJS is represented by <%= EJS =%> -->
```

This comment is executing. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29180611/3776551) question's answer on adding comment within Ejs. As mentioned in the linked question's answer, you should use `<%# comment %>` for the comment.

Finally, if you're trying to include the main `app.js` file in Ejs, then don't. Ejs all about front-end side part. So, you should include scripts that runs in browser.